# How to hide Action Bar in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am using **Android Studio 4.1** and I want to hide the `Action Bar`. I searched stack overflow, but it seems there are some new methods introduced in Android Studio update of October 2020 since `getActionBar().hide();` line method no longer works and app directly crashes. For more clarity, I created a new Project and added nothing else except the `getActionBar().hide();` in the `onCreate()` method. Still the app crashes. My emulator is running on API 30, Android 11 on Pixel 3.

Kindly help.

Comment: What does android studio (IDE) have to do with the Actionbar? Still enough android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in the <activity> tag in manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't depend by Android Studio.
Since you are using a `AppCompatActivity` and you have to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

As alternative you can use a `.NoActionBar` theme, for example.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you don't want action bar any more.then if you are using old base android theme then you can change into this.

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

or if you using new material design then you can change into.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TextOverlayDemo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Thank you, feel free to ask doubts.